# transition from edittext to button

Tags: android

I need transition from edittext to button. When I writing password in edittext, "zaloguj" come up -> https://zapodaj.net/1166d338c3812.png.html but when I click it then application shut off. When I clicked button or 'tab' and next 'enter' then worked properly. But I need system keyboard support

```
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;

/**
 * A login screen that offers login via NIU/password.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /**
     * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

    /**
     * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
     * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
     */
    private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
            "95254:hello"
    };
    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mNIUView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        // Set up the login form.
        mNIUView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.NIU);
        populateAutoComplete();


        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL ) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });


        final Button mNIUSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NIU_sign_in_button);
        mNIUSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
                if (checkLog()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else if(checkNIU()){
                    mPasswordView.setText("");
                }else{
                    mNIUView.setText("");
                    mPasswordView.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
    }

    private void populateAutoComplete() {
        if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
            return;
        }
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
            Snackbar.make(mNIUView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                populateAutoComplete();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid NIU, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    private void attemptLogin() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reset errors.
        mNIUView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String NIU = mNIUView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        if(!exist()){
            mNIUView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_all));
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_all));
            focusView = mNIUView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid NIU
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(NIU)) {
            mNIUView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mNIUView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if(!isNIUValid(NIU)){
            mNIUView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_NIU));
            focusView = mNIUView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!checkNIU() && checkPassword()) {
            mNIUView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_one));
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_one));
            focusView = mNIUView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }else if(!checkPassword() && checkNIU()){
            mNIUView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_one));
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_one));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
            // perform the user login attempt.
            showProgress(true);
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(NIU, password);
            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        }
        mAuthTask = null;
    }
    private boolean isNIUValid(String NIU) {
        try {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(NIU);
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean exist(){
        if(checkLog()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        List<String> NIUs = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            NIUs.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        addEmailsToAutoComplete(NIUs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {}



    private interface ProfileQuery {
        String[] PROJECTION = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
        };

        int ADDRESS = 0;
        int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
    }


    private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> NIUAddressCollection) {
        //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(LoginActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, NIUAddressCollection);

        mNIUView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private boolean checkLog(){
        String email = mNIUView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();
        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(email)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(password);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkNIU(){
        String email = mNIUView.getText().toString();
        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(email))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkPassword(){
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();
        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[1].equals(password))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final String mNIU;
        private final String mPassword;

        UserLoginTask(String NIU, String password) {
            mNIU = NIU;
            mPassword = password;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
            try {
                // Simulate network access.
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }

            for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
                String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
                if (pieces[0].equals(mNIU)) {
                    // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                    return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
                }
            }

            // TODO: register the new account here.
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {
                finish();
            } else {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_one));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }
}
```

and my .xml ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:layout_height="127dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pk" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name_pk"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name_of_pk"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/NIU_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/NIU"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_NIU"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="6"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/NIU_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to download the project?

Comment: https://github.com/DominikaDabek/virtual-deanery

Comment: The app is not crashing on my device

Comment: You use real phone or emulator ?

Comment: I am using a real phone

Comment: Ok, thank you very much <3 so I have to try also

Comment: what error message are you recieving in the`logcat` when the app crashes

Comment: 11-05 23:28:33.364 1134-1134/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1134: eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
11-05 23:28:33.425 1805-1950/com.android.launcher D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f258e250200: ver 2 0
11-05 23:28:33.445 11308-11308/com.edu.pk W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
11-05 23:28:33.489 1673-2546/com.android.inputmethod.latin D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f25846ad200: ver 2 0
11-05 23:28:33.720 11308-11326/com.edu.pk D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f258e257200: ver 2 0

Comment: I also saw when I clicked "tab" but "tab" work properly 11-05 23:32:25.815 1144-1581/? E/AudioMixer: AudioMixer::getTrackName out of available tracks
11-05 23:32:25.815 1144-1581/? E/AudioFlinger: no more track names available
11-05 23:32:25.815 1144-1581/? E/AudioFlinger: createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
11-05 23:32:25.816 1511-1580/system_process E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
11-05 23:32:25.818 1511-1580/system_process E/SoundPool: Error creating AudioTrack

Comment: after 1 minute shows also this -> 11-05 23:34:00.047 1805-1950/com.android.launcher W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...